# How to download fetch response in react as file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

Here is the code in `actions.js`

```
export function exportRecordToExcel(record) {
    return ({fetch}) => ({
        type: EXPORT_RECORD_TO_EXCEL,
        payload: {
            promise: fetch('/records/export', {
                credentials: 'same-origin',
                method: 'post',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                body: JSON.stringify(data)
            }).then(function(response) {
                return response;
            })
        }
    });
}
```

The returned response is an `.xlsx` file. I want the user to be able to save it as a file, but nothing happens. I assume the server is returning the right type of response because in the console it says

```
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="report.xlsx"
```

What am I missing? What should I do in the reducer?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Browser technology currently doesn't support downloading a file directly from an Ajax request. The work around is to add a hidden form and submit it behind the scenes to get the browser to trigger the Save dialog.

I'm running a standard Flux implementation so I'm not sure what the exact Redux (Reducer) code should be, but the workflow I just created for a file download goes like this...

1. I have a React component called `FileDownload`. All this component does is render a hidden form and then, inside `componentDidMount`, immediately submit the form and call it's `onDownloadComplete` prop.
2. I have another React component, we'll call it `Widget`, with a download button/icon (many actually... one for each item in a table). `Widget` has corresponding action and store files. `Widget` imports `FileDownload`.
3. `Widget` has two methods related to the download: `handleDownload` and `handleDownloadComplete`.
4. `Widget` store has a property called `downloadPath`. It's set to `null` by default. When it's value is set to `null`, there is no file download in progress and the `Widget` component does not render the `FileDownload` component.
5. Clicking the button/icon in `Widget` calls the `handleDownload` method which triggers a `downloadFile` action. The `downloadFile` action does NOT make an Ajax request. It dispatches a `DOWNLOAD_FILE` event to the store sending along with it the `downloadPath` for the file to download. The store saves the `downloadPath` and emits a change event.
6. Since there is now a `downloadPath`, `Widget` will render `FileDownload` passing in the necessary props including `downloadPath` as well as the `handleDownloadComplete` method as the value for `onDownloadComplete`.
7. When `FileDownload` is rendered and the form is submitted with `method="GET"` (POST should work too) and `action={downloadPath}`, the server response will now trigger the browser's Save dialog for the target download file (tested in IE 9/10, latest Firefox and Chrome).
8. Immediately following the form submit, `onDownloadComplete`/`handleDownloadComplete` is called. This triggers another action that dispatches a `DOWNLOAD_FILE` event. However, this time `downloadPath` is set to `null`. The store saves the `downloadPath` as `null` and emits a change event.
9. Since there is no longer a `downloadPath` the `FileDownload` component is not rendered in `Widget` and the world is a happy place.

Widget.js - partial code only

```
import FileDownload from './FileDownload';

export default class Widget extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = widgetStore.getState().toJS();
    }

    handleDownload(data) {
        widgetActions.downloadFile(data);
    }

    handleDownloadComplete() {
        widgetActions.downloadFile();
    }

    render() {
        const downloadPath = this.state.downloadPath;

        return (

            // button/icon with click bound to this.handleDownload goes here

            {downloadPath &&
                <FileDownload
                    actionPath={downloadPath}
                    onDownloadComplete={this.handleDownloadComplete}
                />
            }
        );
    }
```

widgetActions.js - partial code only

```
export function downloadFile(data) {
    let downloadPath = null;

    if (data) {
        downloadPath = `${apiResource}/${data.fileName}`;
    }

    appDispatcher.dispatch({
        actionType: actionTypes.DOWNLOAD_FILE,
        downloadPath
    });
}
```

widgetStore.js - partial code only

```
let store = Map({
    downloadPath: null,
    isLoading: false,
    // other store properties
});

class WidgetStore extends Store {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.dispatchToken = appDispatcher.register(action => {
            switch (action.actionType) {
                case actionTypes.DOWNLOAD_FILE:
                    store = store.merge({
                        downloadPath: action.downloadPath,
                        isLoading: !!action.downloadPath
                    });
                    this.emitChange();
                    break;
```

FileDownload.js
- complete, fully functional code ready for copy and paste
- React 0.14.7 with Babel 6.x ["es2015", "react", "stage-0"]
- form needs to be `display: none` which is what the "hidden" `className` is for

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function getFormInputs() {
    const {queryParams} = this.props;

    if (queryParams === undefined) {
        return null;
    }

    return Object.keys(queryParams).map((name, index) => {
        return (
            <input
                key={index}
                name={name}
                type="hidden"
                value={queryParams[name]}
            />
        );
    });
}

export default class FileDownload extends Component {

    static propTypes = {
        actionPath: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        method: PropTypes.string,
        onDownloadComplete: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        queryParams: PropTypes.object
    };

    static defaultProps = {
        method: 'GET'
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).submit();
        this.props.onDownloadComplete();
    }

    render() {
        const {actionPath, method} = this.props;

        return (
            <form
                action={actionPath}
                className="hidden"
                method={method}
            >
                {getFormInputs.call(this)}
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: @nate Can header info be packaged with this form submission?

Comment: @charlie This is a standard HTML form submit. You can use the `enctype` attribute to specify three different values of the Content-Type HTTP header, but that's all. The [Sending form data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data) page on MDN might be helpful. Take a look at the section titled *A special case: sending files*. We have a use case where we first send an Ajax request to generate a download file, then we download. If you can use that option, you'll have more control over the headers in your Ajax request.

Comment: This example is very helpful, but it still isn't clear to me how this implementation knows about whether or not the file has been downloaded. I see that the "onDownloadComplete" is called synchronously after submit, are you just making the assumption that there aren't any errors and that the server receives the request?

Comment: @Himmel Yes, sadly, this work around does not provide a way to confirm the file download was successful. One possible solution could be to send an Ajax request prior to the download (in Widget.js) to confirm the server responds to a GET request to the download file path. Then, if successful, trigger the download. You still aren't confirming the download is successful, but if the file doesn't exist or there's some kind of network error at that time, you could handle the error. You might also want to look into putting the form in an iframe and read the iframe's content using the onload event.

Comment: This is causing me to redirect.  I feel an idiot o_O

Answer (score 44):

You can use these two libs to download files http://danml.com/download.html https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/#filesaverjs

example

```
//  for FileSaver
import FileSaver from 'file-saver';
export function exportRecordToExcel(record) {
      return ({fetch}) => ({
        type: EXPORT_RECORD_TO_EXCEL,
        payload: {
          promise: fetch('/records/export', {
            credentials: 'same-origin',
            method: 'post',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
          }).then(function(response) {
            return response.blob();
          }).then(function(blob) {
            FileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'nameFile.zip');
          })
        }
      });

//  for download 
let download = require('./download.min');
export function exportRecordToExcel(record) {
      return ({fetch}) => ({
        type: EXPORT_RECORD_TO_EXCEL,
        payload: {
          promise: fetch('/records/export', {
            credentials: 'same-origin',
            method: 'post',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
          }).then(function(response) {
            return response.blob();
          }).then(function(blob) {
            download (blob);
          })
        }
      });
```

Comment: thanks for sharing this. The downloadjs is excellent and perfectly solved the problem.

Answer (score 20):

This worked for me.

```
const requestOptions = {
method: 'GET',
headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
};

fetch(`${url}`, requestOptions)
.then((res) => {
    return res.blob();
})
.then((blob) => {
    const href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = href;
    link.setAttribute('download', 'config.json'); //or any other extension
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
})
.catch((err) => {
    return Promise.reject({ Error: 'Something Went Wrong', err });
})
```

Comment: This is what I was expecting, thank you!

Comment: Very compact solution, and it worked as intended !

Answer (score 19):

I have faced the same problem once too.
I have solved it by creating on empty link with a ref to it like so:

```
linkRef = React.createRef();
render() {
    return (
        <a ref={this.linkRef}/>
    );
}
```

and in my fetch function i have done something like this:

```
fetch(/*your params*/)
    }).then(res => {
        return res.blob();
    }).then(blob => {
        const href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const a = this.linkRef.current;
        a.download = 'Lebenslauf.pdf';
        a.href = href;
        a.click();
        a.href = '';
    }).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

basically i have assigned the blobs url(href) to the link, set the download attribute and enforce one click on the link.
As far as i understand this is the "basic" idea of the answer provided by @Nate.
I dont know if this is a good idea to do it this way... I did.

Comment: Dude! U just saved my 2 days of searcing efforts... This is the answer I am looking for

Comment: any idea if there is a max file size on this approach?

Answer (score 5):

I managed to download the file generated by the rest API URL much easier with this kind of code which worked just fine on my local:

```
    import React, {Component} from "react";
    import {saveAs} from "file-saver";

    class MyForm extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const form = event.target;
        let queryParam = buildQueryParams(form.elements);

        let url = 'http://localhost:8080/...whatever?' + queryParam;

        fetch(url, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                // whatever
            },
        })
            .then(function (response) {
                    return response.blob();
                }
            )
            .then(function(blob) {
                saveAs(blob, "yourFilename.xlsx");
            })
            .catch(error => {
                //whatever
            })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} id="whateverFormId">
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" key="myText" name="myText" id="myText"/>
                        </td>
                        <td><input key="startDate" name="from" id="startDate" type="date"/></td>
                        <td><input key="endDate" name="to" id="endDate" type="date"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colSpan="3" align="right">
                            <button>Export</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

function buildQueryParams(formElements) {
    let queryParam = "";

    //do code here
    
    return queryParam;
}

export default MyForm;
```

Comment: a perfect solution

Answer (score 2):

I needed to just download a file onClick but I needed to run some logic to either fetch or compute the actual url where the file existed. I also did not want to use any anti-react imperative patterns like setting a ref and manually clicking it when I had the resource url. The declarative pattern I used was

```
onClick = () => {
  // do something to compute or go fetch
  // the url we need from the server
  const url = goComputeOrFetchURL();

  // window.location forces the browser to prompt the user if they want to download it
  window.location = url
}

render() {
  return (
    <Button onClick={ this.onClick } />
  );
}
```

Comment: I think that this is the most simple and clean answer. No need to generate "fake" actions.

Comment: If the url ends up generating an error response, your nice pretty error handling you probably have in your react app goes right out the window and the user's browser is filled with an ugly error.

Answer (score 2):

I think this solution is maybe a bit more "reactive" than others:

```
import React, { forwardRef, useImperativeHandle, useLayoutEffect, useState } from 'react';

export interface DownloadHandle {
  download: (params: { title: string; data?: Blob }) => void;
}

export const Download = forwardRef<DownloadHandle, {}>((props, ref) => {
  const linkRef = React.useRef<HTMLAnchorElement>(null);
  const [download, setDownload] = useState<{ title: string; data: Blob }>();
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    download: (params) => {
      if (params.data) {
        setDownload(params as typeof download);
      }
    },
  }));

  //trigger download and clear data
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (download) {
      linkRef?.current?.click();
    }
    setDownload(undefined);
  }, [download]);

  if (!download) {
    return null;
  }
  const { title, data } = download;
  return <a href={window.URL.createObjectURL(data)} download={title} ref={linkRef} />;
});

export type DownloadElement = React.ElementRef<typeof Download>;
```

**Usage**

```
const App = () => {

  const downloadRef = useRef<DownloadElement>(null);

  const handleDownload = () => {
    fetch(url, requestOptions)
    .then((res) => res.blob())
    .then((data) => {
      downloadRef.current?.download({ title: `myFile.txt`, data});
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Download ref={downloadRef} />
      <button onClick={}>Download</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```