# Resume prevented event in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When user clicks on `<a>`, I want to first get a new `href` resolved by a promise, and then trigger the change of window location. But I can't find a good practice to do this.

To conclude, here's psuedo code:

```
getNewUrl = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  fetchUrl.then(newUrl => {
     newUrl = newUrl;
     e.resumeEvent();
  })
}

<a 
  href={newUrl}
  onClick={this.getNewUrl}
/>
```

But obviously there's no e.resumeEvent(). What should I do to handle this?
(Don't want to fetch url massively in `componentDidMount()`, as there might be many requests)

Comment: I have found a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35206589/how-to-download-fetch-response-in-react-as-file
It's workable but I'm surprised that it needs so much effort for such a common task. Any better solution is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want to change a window location.

`window.location = newUrl`

should do that trick.

Comment: Hmm two issues with this: 1. Expecting to see a new tab being opened, not changing the current window location, as the url is for downloading; 2. Since it's a React context, kinda prefer to solve in a React way.