# Can static content on spring-boot-web application be dynamic (refreshed)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am still searching around this subject, but I cannot find a simple solution, and I don't sure it doesn't exist.

**Part 1**

- I have a service on my application that's generating an excel doc, by the dynamic DB data.

  ```
   public static void 
   notiSubscribersToExcel(List<NotificationsSubscriber> 
   data) {
   //generating the file dynamically from DB's data

   String prefix = "./src/main/resources/static";
   String directoryName = prefix + "/documents/";
   String fileName = directoryName + "subscribers_list.xlsx";

   File directory = new File(directoryName);
   if (! directory.exists()){
       directory.mkdir();
       // If you require it to make the entire directory path including parents,
       // use directory.mkdirs(); here instead.
   }

   try (OutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(fileName)) {

       wb.write(fileOut);
       fileOut.close();
       wb.close();

   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IOException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
  ```

**Part 2**

I want to access it from the browser, so when I call it will get downloaded.
I know that for the static content, all I need to do is to call to the file, from the browser like that:

> http://localhost:8080/documents/myfile.xlsx

[image: Example]

After I would be able to do it, all I need is to create link to this url from my client app.

**The problem -**
Currently if I call to the file as above, it will download only the file which have been there in the compiling stage, but if I am generating a new files after the app is running the content won't be available.

It seems that the content is (as it's called) "static" and cannot be changed after startup.

**So my question is**

- is there is a way to define a folder on the app structure that will be dynamic? I just want to access the new generated file.

**BTW** I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24762657/refreshing-static-content-with-spring-mvc-and-boot) answer and others which doing configuration methods, or web services, but I don't want all this. And I have tried some of them, but the result is the same.

**FYI** I don't bundle my client app with the server app, I run them from different hosts

Comment: It's not clear what you really want. You say you want the file dynamically but the file is already generated. Which part would be dynamic?

Comment: @GaëlJ I meant that it's generated with other content by the client but I got the old content

Comment: Which client? Please update your question with more details like a scenario of what is happening and what you'd expect.

Comment: @GaëlJ, I edited the post. Hope that now it's clearer.

Comment: A couple of ideas: 1 - don't write in `src/main/resources`, the folder would not exist on a production server 2 - don't use static serving of the file but implement a controller that will read the file content and send it back to the caller

Comment: @GaëlJ thanks, I'll try it

Comment: If you want your app to be truly dynamic, then you should dynamically create the Excel doc at run-time using a Java lib such as http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/current/docs/jxl/Workbook.html.

Comment: @smac2020 that's what I'm doing. The problem is to download the file with the dynamic content

Comment: See code below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***The problem is to download the file with the dynamic content from a Spring app.***

This can be solved with Spring BOOT. Here is the solution as shown in this illustration - when i click Download report, my app generates a dynamic Excel report and its downloaded to the browser:

[image]

From a JS, make a get request to a Spring Controller:

```
function DownloadReport(e){

     //Post the values to the controller
     window.location="../report" ;
}
```

Here is the Spring Controller GET Method with /report:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = ["/report"], method = [RequestMethod.GET])
    @ResponseBody
    fun report(request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse) {

       
        // Call exportExcel to generate an EXCEL doc with data using jxl.Workbook
        val excelData = excel.exportExcel(myList)
        try {

            // Download the report.
            val reportName  = "ExcelReport.xls"
            response.contentType  = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=$reportName")
            org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(excelData, response.outputStream)
            response.flushBuffer()

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

This code is implemented in Kotlin - but you can implement it as easily in Java too.

Comment: Cool! man, exactly what I needed. I already succeed to handle the part of the server side, but I was stuck with how to make manually navigation to to the link. Your window.location, is the Brilliant simplicity. 

please consider to post your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35206589/how-to-download-fetch-response-in-react-as-file

because you solve the problem without all this exaggerated workarounds.